# Monitor Azure Function App based on its Metrics

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have provisioned Azure Functions App and created a function into it. The Run time of the Function App is .Net core. Since we are planning to push the Functions to production we need to ensure to get alerts if any error occurred on Function App like HTTP Server error.

I just wanted to know if this can be done using Application Insights.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the Application Insights configured for your Function App. There should be a button "Alerts", where you can configure E-Mail-notifications for a custom query.

Checkout the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/alerts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I can only configure a couple of metrics in a single alert, there are a bunch of metrics I need to configure to a single alerting system. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: You should be able to add multiple Conditions and Actions to your Alert Rule. Make sure you selected the Application Insights configured for your Function App. Then select Monitoring > Alerts > New Alert Rule.